# How to get Rails' acts_as_list to add new items to the beginning of a list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-list

I have a model integrated with [acts_as_list](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list). However, by default new items created get added to the *end* of the list. Is there a default way to add new items to the *beginning*?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Try using the `add_new_at` configuration option:

```
acts_as_list scope: :todo, add_new_at: :top
```

Comment: This is the best answer. I deleted my answer about the column default method as it no longer works.

Comment: @yuval you should accept this answer as it's still valid, and is the official method.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the way the list items are displayed to begin with. Reversing the order of `todo_items` effectively accomplishes that.

`has_many :todo_items, :order => "position ASC"`

Otherwise, perhaps you can set the `position` column on the items manually in an `after_create`.

Comment: This might break under the assumption that the OP has some kind of drag and drop reordering in their app. This would attempt to reorder all items according to their index position in the array of ids. Just something to be aware of.